# R - Parse text file as fscanf ?

Tags: r

I have a large text file that I want to import in R with multimodal data encoded as such :

```
A=1,B=1,C=2,...
A=2,B=1,C=1,...
A=1,B=2,C=1,...
```

What I'd like to have is a dataframe similar to this :

```
A    B    C
1    1    2
2    1    1
1    2    1
```

Because the column name is being repeated over and over for each row, I was wondering if there was a way import that text file with a fscanf functionality that would parse the A, B, C column names such as "A=%d,B=%d,C=%d,...."

Or maybe there's a simpler way using read.table or scan ? But I couldn't figure out how.

Thanks for any tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) read.pattern** `read.pattern` in the gsubfn package is very close to what you are asking.  Instead of `%d` use `(\\d+)` when specifying the pattern.  If the column names are not important the `col.names` argument could be omitted.

```
library(gsubfn)    
L <- c("A=1,B=1,C=2", "A=1,B=1,C=2", "A=1,B=1,C=2") # test input

pat <- "A=(\\d+),B=(\\d+),C=(\\d+)"
read.pattern(text = L, pattern = pat, col.names = unlist(strsplit(pat, "=.*?(,|$)")))
```

giving:

```
  A B C
1 1 1 2
2 1 1 2
3 1 1 2
```

**1a) percent format** Just for fun we could implement it using exactly the format given in the question.

```
fmt <- "A=%d,B=%d,C=%d"
pat <- gsub("%d", "(\\\\d+)", fmt)
```

Now run the `read.pattern` statement above.

**2) strapply** Using the same input and the gsubfn package, again, an alternative is to pull out all strings of digits eliminating the need for the `pat` shown in (1) reducing the pattern to just `"\\d+"`.

```
DF <- strapply(L, "\\d+", as.numeric, simplify = data.frame)
names(DF) <- unlist(strsplit(L[1], "=.*?(,|$)"))
```

**3) read.csv** Even simpler is this base only solution which deletes the headings and reads in what is left setting the column names as in the prior solution.  Again, omit the `col.names` argument if column names are not important.

```
read.csv(text = gsub("\\w*=", "", L), header = FALSE,
  col.names = unlist(strsplit(L[1], "=.*?(,|$)")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it to work with 3). I used L = readLines('mydata.txt'). I had to disable col.names though. I'll sort it out later !